# Convert a key value data frame to a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

This is the type of structure I have.  There is a few thousand rows in a data frame that has similar structure to the following:

```
vct_names <- c("apples", "apples", "grapes", "apples", "grapes")
vct_codes <- c(23, 35, 123, 43, 156)
df_values <- data.frame(names = vct_names, codes = vct_codes)
```

I want to convert the data frame above into a named list. I would like to iterate through each row of the data frame above and convert this data frame to a list.  The list would have the following structure:

```
lst_values <- list()
lst_values$apples <- c(23, 35, 43)
lst_values$grapes <- c(123, 156)
```

Any ideas on an elegant way to solving this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `split`-function is precisely designed to do that. It works on both dataframes and on vectors as the first agument. It does this polymorphic act by being a generic function.

```
> methods(split)
[1] split.data.frame  split.data.table* split.Date        split.default    
[5] split.IDate*      split.POSIXct     split.zoo*       
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

So this would be more economical:

```
> lst_values <- split(vct_codes, vct_names)
> lst_values
$apples
[1] 23 35 43

$grapes
[1] 123 156
```

In this case we are using `split.default`. Sometimes it's informative to print out the code, but in this case we only see some preliminary manipulation of edge cases before the data and arguments are passed to `.Internal(split(seq_along(x), f))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(split(df_values, df_values$names), function(z) z[,2])

$apples
[1] 23 35 43

$grapes
[1] 123 156
```

Comment: Its a beauty!  Do we need to nest split() inside lapply()  split(df_values, df_values$names) seems to work really well.

Comment: `split()` splits the data.frame into many data.frame's in a list, so need to iterate over each data.frame and pull out just the one column of values

Comment: No need for lapply. The split function will work on vectors and return a named list.

Comment: Not to mention that split + lapply = `?by`